# JavaScript ternary operator usage clarification

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small script, using the ternary operator for short-hand 'if' statements. The code is below:

```
self.checked ? psswrd[z].type = 'text' : psswrd[z].type = 'password';
```

This essentially says, if the input is checked, make the input type 'text', else make it password. I have a feeling this is wrong in the sense I am repeating myself.

Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
psswrd[z].type ? 'text' : 'password';
```

But how can I check the 'if' part of it being checked? I am new to this ternary method so explanations would go a long way, and thank you.

The full loop if needed:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < checkz.length; j++ ) {

            var self = checkz[j];
            self.onchange = function () {
                for ( var z = 0; z < psswrd.length; z++ ) {

                    self.checked ? psswrd[z].type = 'text' : psswrd[z].type = 'password';

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator `?:` used like `[condition] ? [code1] : [code2]` evaluates the `condition` and if it is evaluated to true it will return `code1`, otherwise `code2`. It will never happen that both `code1` and `code2` will be evaluated, just one of them. That´s why

`var abc = test == null ? "no" : test.something()`

will work both if test is null or not.

The operator is generally used in assigments like `a = condition ? code1 : code2`, then it is equivalent to

```
if (condition)
  a = code1;
else 
  a = code2;
```

In your case you would have to use

`psswrd[z].type = self.checked ? 'text' : 'password';`

which is euivalent to

```
if (self.checked)
  psswrd[z].type = 'text';
else 
  psswrd[z].type = 'password';
```

Little variations of the general use would be just `condition ? code1 : code2` what would just cause either code1 or code2 to be executed and the return value would be discarded.
Or you can use it inside another assigment like `var num = 17 + (test ? -17 : 25)` which will set num to 0 if test is evaluated to true or to 42 if it is evaluated to false.

Answer (score 6):

Simply do

```
 psswrd[z].type = self.checked ? 'text' : 'password';
```

This is also much more readable. I would recommend to more generally avoid to use the ternary operator to replace a `if` statement unless the code appears to be clear enough.

Comment: Ah, get it now. It's got to be used in an assignment! Thank you that's really helped. Yep I have read that you're meant to only use it for simplicity, I think this one is simple enough.

Comment: When you use it in an assignment, it's fine. That's the most classical use.